# Prove the statement is false

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

My goal is to show that the following statement is false:

let {v<sub>1</sub>, ... , v<sub>n</sub>} be vectors in a vector space V and let T:V→W be a linear transformation.
if {v<sub>1</sub>, ... , v<sub>n</sub>} is linearly independent in V, { T(v<sub>1</sub>), ... , T(v<sub>n</sub>)}  is linearly independent in W.

Not really sure if there is a way i can prove its false other than with a simple counterexample. I feel like there is a counterexample in R<sup>2</sup> but im having trouble thinking of one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

One counterexample is enough to disprove this. Take $T = 0$.

The converse of this statement is true though.

Comment: Is there any other counter example? That one seems like the obvious one, but are there more?

Comment: @MikeWimms Another one: Let $T(x,y) = x:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Then the image of linearly independent vectors $(1,0),(0,1)$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. That makes so much sense when you describe it like that!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\text{dim}\,V=n$ and $\text{Ker}\,T\ne\{0\}$. Thus, there is a $v\in V$ such that $v\ne 0$ and $T(v)=0$. We know $\{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ are independent and $\text{dim}\,V=n$, therefore we can write $v=\alpha_1 v_1+\cdots\alpha_n v_n$. we have

$$T(v)=T(\alpha v_1+\cdots+\alpha v_n)=\alpha_1 T(v_1)+\cdots +\alpha_n T(v_n)=0$$ 
Thus we can say $\{T(v_1),\cdots ,T(v_n)\}$ are not independent.